# LInk does not work with jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and CodeIgniter. In my index page,

```
http://localhost:8888/hwezemail2/index.php/welcome/student/index
```

I have a link to another page.

```
http://localhost:8888/hwezemail2/index.php/welcome/student/myhomework/56
```

But when I click the link, it will go to the following and does not display.

```
http://localhost:8888/hwezemail2/index.php/welcome/student/index#/hwezemail2/
index.php/welcome/student/myhomework/56
```

Then I refresh the page once the url becomes

```
http://localhost:8888/hwezemail2/index.php/welcome/student/myhomework/56
```

But it does not display the content. So I refresh it again then it shows the content.

Once it shows, then I don't have any problem. It is only the first time.

My PHP code it the following.

```
echo '<a href="'. base_url().'index.php/welcome/student/myhomework/'
.$userid.'" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop" 
data-icon="star" data-mini="true" data-theme="c">Missed Homework</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I added data-ajax="false" to the link and the problem was solved.